# Safari CSS - min-height and background-size

Tags: safari, css

So here's the problem. I've set a background image that resizes until a minimun height is reached. At least this is how it behaves in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

```
body {
    min-height: 790px; 
    min-width: 640px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#main {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/index_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

But in Safari, if I continue making my navigator's window's height smaller than 790px, the background image continues resizing. When my idea is that it should stop at 790px as it does in other navigators. Vertical scroll does appear but of course this is not much help when the background continues resizing.

If you want to check out the whole page for its code, here it is:

http://www.avalon.me/313/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest also setting the min height value of #main. This worked for me in all browsers.

```
#main{ min-height:790px; }
```

Comment: Great, that seemed to do it! Thanks!!